# Conditional statement (truth table) formula on Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, truthtable

What is the formula for `p=>q`?

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this even a question?! No indication of what you are trying to do / have done already. Please try to be clear and concise in the future, providing where possible, some example data and expected output. It really helps us understand what is going on. People will not be willing to put their time and effort into something that indicates you have not put any effort in on your part.

Comment: I see a title and tags.  Where is the text for the question?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why this question got all this hate but it is quite an interesting question if you think about it. Let me try to explain.

In excel you have functions for the main logic gates:

- **OR gate** [p∨q]: `=OR(p,q)`
- **AND gate** [p∧q]: `=AND(p,q)`
- **NOT gate** [~p]: `=NOT(p)`

So the natural assumption is, what about the conditional gate? [p→q] is there also a function that excel has that would give me the conditional expected response? `=something(p,q) maybe`

**The answer is no there is not.**

> There is still hope! You can still use a very nice and important identity:
>
> > **[p→q] = [~p∨q]**
> >
> > `=OR(NOT(p),q)`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The last column would be:

```
⟶ 
True
False
True
True
```

The excel formula for that:

```
=IF(AND(B3,NOT(C3)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

If you put that in `H3` and drag it down, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but you can also use `=IF(P, Q, TRUE)`.

The IF function takes in three parameters: condition, value if true, and value if false. When P is false, we will always return true by vacuous truth, and when P is true, we return the value of Q.

We can look at the truth table of P -> Q to convince ourselves of this.

Here's the half of the table where P is true and we return Q.

| P | Q | P -> Q |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | Q (T) |
| T | F | Q (F) |

Here is the other half where P is false and we return false.

| P | Q | P -> Q |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | T | T |
| F | F | T |